# Existence of a Precise axiomatization of Eudoxus theory of magnitude

Tags: euclidean-geometry, real-numbers, axioms

Is there a precise axiomatization of the Eudoxus theory of proportions? For example,

a) (D, +, <) is a structure such that < is a strict linear order,

b) + is an order-preserving  commutative and associative operation which is order-preserving,

c) for every x there is y such that nx =y,

d) Eudoxus-Archimede Axiom,

e) Continuity axiom …

Comment: Somewhat tangentially, you may be interested in the "Eudoxus construction" of the real numbers; I think [Arthan's exposition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405454.pdf) is a good starting point. There are a couple of questions at mathoverflow on various generalizations, but they don't seem to have gotten much traction.

Comment: I am aware of the suggested paper but:

Comment: Tanks. I am aware of the suggested paper, but while it is very elegant and simple from a mathematical point of view, it is not clear for me the connection with the ancient Eudoxus theory. In any case my question is to justify a common claim "Eudoxus theory is equivalent with real number theory". To face this question I need a precise system of axioms for Eudoxus theory. Obviously, this leads also to  the question of the meaning of the expression "equivalent theories" in the case the lanquages are different.

Comment: From a Mathematical point of view we have to prove that the operation of product and inverse defined by proportion theory toghether with the sum define in a class of omogeneous magnitudes a structure isomorphic with the algebraic structure of the positive real numbers (once an unity is fixed, obviously)